# Which syntax rule matches the def foo(a, *, b=10) compound statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

[The formal syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) for parameters in function definitions is as follows:

```
parameter_list ::=  (defparameter ",")*                                        #[1]
                    | "*" [parameter] ("," defparameter)* ["," "**" parameter] #[2]
                    | "**" parameter                                           #[3]
                    | defparameter [","] )                                     #[4]
```

*(`#[num]` added by me for clarity)*

[*Where `|`, according to the notation, indicates alternatives.*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/introduction.html#notation)

I can't see how exactly it matches the following function definition:

```
def foo(a, *, b=10): pass
```

The obvious rule where one would suppose a definition of the form `def foo(a, *, b=10)` would fall under is `#[2]` which allows for the `*` notation to seperate keyword-only parameters.

But the rule for `foo`, from what I would of thought, would have to be a combination of `#[1]` and `#[2]`:

```
parameter_list ::= (defparameter ",")* "*" [parameter] ("," defparameter)* ["," "**" parameter]
```

Since rule `#[1]` and `#[2]` *don't seem to match this case solely on their own*.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you read further down there?  *If a parameter has a default value, all following parameters up until the “\*” must also have a default value —* ***this is a syntactic restriction that is not expressed by the grammar.***

Comment: Doesn't that simply specify that a call of the form `def foo(*, a, b=10)` is illegal?

Comment: Looks like it’s wrong, unless I’m also missing something. The last closing parenthesis doesn’t have a corresponding opening one.

Comment: @Jim Interesting. I am not sure but I guess it must be #2 somehow. (Will wait for an answer)

Comment: @BhargavRao apparently it was a silly little typo which caused me to read all this wrong. Damn these can be frustrating.

Comment: Oh damn, what is the world heading to? Typos in the documentation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formal syntax appears to be missing an opening parenthesis. The last closing one doesn’t match anything, and if you look at [the Python 2 version](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions), it makes perfect sense:

```
parameter_list ::=  (defparameter ",")*
                    (  "*" identifier ["," "**" identifier]
                    | "**" identifier
                    | defparameter [","] )
```

So just read it as:

```
parameter_list ::=  (defparameter ",")*
                    ( "*" [parameter] ("," defparameter)* ["," "**" parameter]
                    | "**" parameter
                    | defparameter [","] )
```

Someone probably replaced the `(` with a `|` while realigning things.

Comment: I’ll try submitting an issue in the morning… but the issue tracker is impossible to search…

Comment: Yup, that would indeed make perfect sense. If they do eventually reply, try and remember to add it to your answer if you can.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm, as Pointed out by Ryan, it definitely looks like a documentation bug.

This is how the actual language grammar is defined, for the [function declaration syntax](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v3.5.0/Grammar/Grammar#l27) in Python v3.5.0

```
funcdef: 'def' NAME parameters ['->' test] ':' suite

parameters: '(' [typedargslist] ')'

typedargslist: (tfpdef ['=' test] (',' tfpdef ['=' test])*
    [',' ['*' [tfpdef] (',' tfpdef ['=' test])* [',' ['**' tfpdef [',']]] | '**' tfpdef [',']]]
  | '*' [tfpdef] (',' tfpdef ['=' test])* [',' ['**' tfpdef [',']]]
  | '**' tfpdef [','])
```

Here, [`tfpdef` is the identifier](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Grammar/Grammar#l35)

```
tfpdef: NAME [':' test]
```

and `test` is the same as the [`expression`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-expression)

```
test: or_test ['if' or_test 'else' test] | lambdef
```